# Como obter o caminho para a minha base de dados SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Necessito que a minha app permita efetuar o backup e restore dos dados que estão gravados no SQLite. Segui alguns tutoriais da internet mas não estou a conseguir fazer a cópia dos dados!

```
String packageName = contexto.getPackageName();
String NOME_BD = "estudos_sql.bd";
String BD_FILEPATH = "/data/data/" + packageName + "/databases/" + NOME_BD;
```

O meu problema é que não encontro o ficheiro da base de dados (`BD_FILEPATH`) apesar de esta estar a funcionar normalmente!!!??? Será problema de permissões?

Comment: Você está no Windows ou Linux (ou FreeBSD, Mac OS X, …)? Esse diretório “`/data/data/…`” fica na raiz do seu sistema?

Comment: app está a correr no Android (emulador ou dispositivo fisico)...

Comment: Editei o título da pergunta tentando conseguir que ele melhor expresse a sua dúvida. Caso não concorde com a alteração clique [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/67629/revisions), para aceder ao histórico das revisões, e depois no link ***reverter*** da revisão anterior a esta.

Answer (score 4):

Se a sua base de dados foi criada da forma tradicional, usando a classe *SQLiteOpenHelper*, poderá obter o caminho dela através de:

```
String dbPath = context.getDatabasePath("nome da db").toString();
```

Comment: Olá ramaral! Estive analizar melhor o meu problema e este não está no ficheiro de entrada mas está antes no ficheiro de saida. Da-me sempre erro de FileNotFoundException. Aqui vai o meu código a ver se me podem ajudar:

Comment: <code>String dbPath = contexto.getDatabasePath("estudos_sql.bd").toString();
            File dbFile = new File(dbPath);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
            String outFileName = "backup.db";
            File outFile = new File(outFileName);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }</code>

Comment: O erro capturado através do "getMessage()" é: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system). Este indica que não tenho permissão de escrita na memória interna do Android! O que necessito de fazer para libertar a permissão de escrita na memória interna?

Comment: Altere `File outFile = new File(outFileName);` por `File outFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), outFileName);`

Comment: ramaral, com essa configuração funciona. Agora estou com outro problema que é encontrar no Android o ficheiro de backup. Se eu alterar a localização do ficheiro de "./backup.db" para "/mnt/sdcard/backup.db" obtenho o erro "open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)". Consegue ajudar-me novamente?

Comment: Se quer gravar no *sdcard* em vez de `context.getFilesDir()` terá de usar [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29). Tenha em conta que em ambos os casos os ficheiros são apagados quando a app for desinstalada. Veja todas as possibilidades [aqui](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage)

Comment: Não codifique directamente(*hard code*) o caminho do ficheiro, use sempre um dos métodos que eu indiquei para obter o caminho ao directório, adicione depois o nome do ficheiro.

Comment: Obrigado ramaral. Caso necessite de mais ajuda, volto cá novamente...

Comment: ramaral, o meu problema principal ficou resolvido. Só mais uma duvida: Através da configuração "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" o ficheiro de backup vai ser criado na raiz do Armazenamento Externo do Smartphone. Contudo eu pretendia que ele fosse antes criado na raiz do cartão SD externo. Que configuração tenho de aplicar?

Comment: De facto há *Smartphones* que têm incorporado um *"External Storage"* além do *sdcard*. Infelizmente o *path* retornado por  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` refere-se ao primeiro. Para complicar mais as coisas o *path* para o *sdcard* pode variar de marca para marca e mesmos entre modelos da mesma marca. Encontrei [aqui](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-finding-sd-card-path.html) um código que autor afirma funcionar na maioria dos *devices*.

Comment: ramaral, mais uma vez obrigado. Vou analisar o código.